# selenium is trowing an error as element is not visible

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have the java script injection to send text into a hidden inputbox. but webdriver is throwing an error as element is not visible so cannot be interacted with.

```
WebElement tmpElement= driver.findElement(By.className("cwd_input"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
executor.executeScript(("document.getElementsByClassName('cwd_input')
   [0].click();"),tmpElement); 
tmpElement.sendKeys("T");
```

Comment: couple of things to ask. Is tmpElement the only element on the page with the class name "cwd_input"? and why are you selecting the element twice? And clicking with Javascript?

Comment: WebDriver is supposed to mimic user behavior, how would a user enter something into a hidden input? What you are asking for violates the main concepts behind WebDriver.

Comment: @Erik M: In the application i have to click on a button and type text, which will be stored in an input box and then reflect back on the screen in a  table, If I directly try to enter text into the table, it doesn't allow. when i click the next button and type the text ,the input box gets refreshed and newly entered text gets displayed  on screen inside the table. Can I email you the screen shot of the webpage

Comment: @cathal : yes, there is  only one "cwd_input" class element, because I am not getting the option to sendkeys in document.getElements... I am clicking first and sending keys next. I am able to get it work in selenium IDE, its simple operation, one command to click the button, another to sendkeys into cwd_input, however in webdriver its failing.

Comment: Can you provide the `html` of the element you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

you can set value of the input via JS.
Code will be something like:

```
string scriptToExecute = "document.getElementById("mytext").value = 'New value';";

executor.executeScript(scriptToExecute);
```